# How to echo SQL col to specific '<td>' in HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to insert

```
echo "<td>" . $row['stock_code']."</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['stock_type']."</td>";
```

from second `td` onwards. Is it possible?

this is my code:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'; //connect to db
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT stock_code,stock_type FROM stock");// query two col
//create table
echo '<table border="1" style="width:100%">
<tr> 
<th>Invoice</th>
<th>Stock Code</th>
<th>Stock Type</th>
........
<th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
';

//fetch data from db
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
// insert into tables
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['stock_code']."</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['stock_type']."</td>";
echo "<tr>";
}
echo "</table>"
?>
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish. What's the desired result? What have you tried, and why didn't that work?

Comment: my html tables begins like Invoice- Stock Code- Stock Type. when i fetch stock_code from sql, i want to insert in second col "Stock Code", but it inserts in first col in html table.

Comment: screen shot. http://imgur.com/jYZ1xzN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just echo a `<td></td>` first. Example..

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td></td>"; //Invoice
    echo "<td>" . $row['stock_code']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['stock_type']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Its working. so i have to skip colums right. Is there any other way to insert to like third or fourth columns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the structure of the table in your code. It has **4 table headings (th)** for  Invoice, Stock Code, Stock Type and Quantity but inside your while loop you are creating only **2 table columns (td)**.

You can either remove the unnecessary table headings:

```
//create table
echo '<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr> 
        <th>Stock Code</th>
        <th>Stock Type</th>
    </tr>
';
```

OR

fetch the data and create the columns (td) for Invoice and Quantity inside your while loop like this:

```
//fetch data from db
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    // insert into tables
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['invoice'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['stock_code'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['stock_type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}
echo "</table>"
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I thought there might be a way like - Insert this "1st SQL row" into "2nd html column".

Comment: @veneshprivin This can be accomplished by playing with the code that I provided. You just have to keep the same number of "th" and "td" in the structure of the table that you are creating and "move" the SQL data to the column that you want it to appear.